# How to apply Theme from ThemeRoller on JqGrid in Django framework

Tags: django, jqgrid, themes

I'm developing my first Django app and I try to understand how to apply a ThemeRoller theme on my JqGrid.
Where should I put the files after downloading the archive on https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ ?

My CSS and JS files are currently on the Static folder and everything is ok for me to access those files but i just don't know where to put the folder / files to get it to work...

Am i supposed to override the existants files ? or add them somewhere and just call them ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you build new theme with theme roller you build new set of css file and images.

To set the new theme in jqGrid you will need to overwrite the existing jquery UI css file and image directory in your distribution. This usually is in the css directory of jqGrid. Be a sure to have the same names when overwriting.

It will be good then to clear the browser cache.

Comment: Ok but how come there are also .js files in the archive when you download the theme ? What are they for ? shouldn't I use them too ?

Comment: When you select theme and click download you go to download builder, in which you can select what to download. This include jquery and jquery ui js files too. You can or you can't replace them too.

Comment: Ok got it.  Is there any purpose replacing theme ? Or is it useless ?